# Where to set 'use_blender_profile' option?

Tags: collada

I have seen that the Collada exporter uses a flag called `use_blender_profile`.

Looking at the source file, it seems that this option allows to export additional information in the Collada file :

- `connect` to say if the bone is connected to its parent
- `tip_x`, `tip_y`, `tip_z` to tell the length of the leaf bones

Without these values, the information is lost as Collada encodes the armature differently.

But where and how `use_blender_profile` can be set ?
Am I right about the exporter behavior ?

The blend file : [image]

Comment: I would report that as a bug. The code appears to be there and there is no conditions to show/hide it. It is listed in the rna/dna files and it's in the operator and layout functions with the other options that are visible. I don't see any reason the option should not be available during export.

Comment: @sambler thanks, have a look from the line 177 of ArmatureExporter.cpp (current version). How to report that ?

Comment: That's where the option actually changes the exported data. The problem is earlier in that the option is not made available to be turned on/off. You report the bug at [developer.blender.org](https://developer.blender.org), you can simply write file xx/yyy/this.c or you can add links in the bug report the same as here using `[text](link/to/file$linenumber)` adding `$177` to the end of the url will reference a specific line.

Comment: OK... first time I do that, but done : https://developer.blender.org/T48801?workflow=create. Thanks @sambler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You find the setting in the exporter's option pannel:

[image]

Note that this is a new option (added in june 2016). This option will become available in Blender 2.7.8. Of course you can download the most recent nightly build. There you should find this option as well.